# How to test if MethodInfo.ReturnType is type of System.Void?

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo

Using reflection to obtain a MethodInfo, I want to test if the type returned is typeof System.Void.

Testing if it is System.Int32 works fine

```
 myMethodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(System.Int32)
```

but

```
 myMethodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(System.Void)
```

does not compile? At present Im testing if the string representation of the name is "System.Void" which seems very wrong.

Comment: what error are you getting when building that code?

Comment: If a method returns Void, it means it does not return anything, so why not reverse the logic and check for what could be returned?  Just an idea...

Comment: Compiler says "System.Void cannot be used from C# -- use typeof(void) to get the void type". Ah, just read the error. DOH!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can't use [`System.Void`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.void.aspx) directly, but can access it using `typeof(void)`.

Several people point out ([here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/matthew.podwysocki/archive/2008/06/06/functional-c-revisited-into-the-great-void.aspx) and in the comments [here](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/06/05/forbidden-void-type-in-c.aspx) for example) that the reason for this is that the [ECMA Standard 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-335.pdf), Partition II, section 9.4 says:

> The following kinds of type cannot be
>   used as arguments in instantiations
>   (of generic types or methods):
>
> - Byref types (e.g., `System.Generic.Collection.List 1<string&>`
>     is invalid)
> - Value types that contain fields that can point into the CIL
>     evaluation stack (e.g.,`List<System.RuntimeArgumentHandle>`)
> - void (e.g., `List<System.Void>` is invalid)

Comment: No more hiding the error window! ;) But it is awfully strange.

Answer (score 20):

When I build this, I get the error:

> System.Void cannot be used from C# -- use typeof(void) to get the void type object

Sounds like that's the answer...

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
if(methodInfo.ReturnType.Name == "Void"){
  // Your Code.........
}
```

Comment: I can create a class and name it Void, at least check that the Fullname is 'System.Void', still ugly as hell